# Date difference in days with decimal value, and excluding weekends

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to get the exact amount of days between two timestamps (ex. 1.45 days). The thing is BigQuery datediff function rounds the day and only accepts 2 timestamp arguments.

```
SELECT
datediff(start_time_pac_tz, end_time_pac_tz) as Date_difference
```

> Date_difference
>
> -6

Also I'm looking to exclude weekends. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(<timestamp>)`, and take a day = a second * 60 * 60 * 24.

```
SELECT
    ((TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(end_time_pac_tz) - TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(start_time_pac_tz)) / (60 * 60 * 24) + 1)
  -((WEEK(end_time_pac_tz) - WEEK(start_time_pac_tz)) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(start_time_pac_tz) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(end_time_pac_tz) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  as Date_difference
```